# DropdownList in ASP.NET MVC - value not posted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a form in ASP MVC (Razor) and in this form I have a Textboxes... and a `<select>` and I want to transmit the selected option (value) of this select to the controller like the other information. The textboxes are transmitted correctly to the controller and it's in the database.

I have a field in the database called NumberParticipant and I want to transmit i tin the database thanks to my Create controller :

My code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocalNumber, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LocalNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocalNumber)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <select class="form-control" id="numberParticipant">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Comment: Your `<select>` has no `name` attribute so nothing is posted back. (and why not bind to a model property and use `@Html.DropDownListFor()`)

Comment: I think about the DropDownListFor but how can I put in this DropDownListFor the options 2,3,4,5 and the first option null ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the MVC DropDownList helper would save you from writing out all the html. Here's an example that sets the option values in the view.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NumberParticipant, 
        new SelectList(new [] 
        { new {value="",text=""},
          new {value="2",text="2"},
          new {value="3",text="3"},
          new {value="4",text="4"},
          new {value="5",text="5"}
    },"value","text"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
</div>
```

A best practice would be to add a property of type SelectList to your model class and set the possible options there. You could then reference the new property in the helper like this:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NumberParticipant, 
        Model.MySelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
</div>
```

Comment: new SelectList("","2","3","4","5"), I can't put 5 items in that

Comment: Good point! I've just edited my answer to correct the syntax for populating the SelectList. I'd recommend creating a SelectList property in the model and using the second approach though if possible.

Comment: My options don't have a value for example the 2 the value must be 2 <option value="2">2</option>

Comment: @user3524214, When you select the option with the display text of `2`, then a value of `2` will be posted back (if there is no explicit `value` attribute, then the text is used).