# MVC form submit won send the select tag selected option

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms, html-select

I have an MVC form with an HTML select tag inside.
The select is populated from JavaScript.
How do I send the selected option with the form submit?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginFromTest", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login failed. Check your login details.");
    <div style="margin: 10px;">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                Username: 
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="text" name="user" />
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                Password: 
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="password" name="password" />
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                Authority:
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <select id="authority" />
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
            <br/>
            @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.Error))
            {
                <span style="color: red;">@ViewBag.Error</span>
            }
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `name` attribute to assign select name which later submitted to controller action method using `Bind`/`Include`. But it is better to use `DropDownList(For)` with model binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DropdownList in ASP.NET MVC - value not posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514830/dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc-value-not-posted)

Comment: Just give it a `name` matching the property of your model or the argument of your Action method. Then submit the form as normal

Comment: Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto - I totally missed it and used id attribute instead of name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming your action method looks something like:

```
public ActionResult LoginFromTest(string user, string password, string authority)
```

you just need to give your select a name matching the parameter you want it to populate:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
    <select id="authority" name="authority">
        <option value="X" />
        <option value="Y" />
    </select>
</div>
```

If your binding to a model your model will need to be:

```
public class myModel
{
   public string username {get; set;}
   public string password {get; set;}
   public string authority {get; set;}
}
```

your action will then look like:

```
public ActionResult LoginFromTest(myModel model)
```

but the name remains the same. You can also use the [`@Html.DropDowListFor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27514990/542251) and `@Html.DropDownList` helpers but it's perfectly possible to do this using flat HTML.

Comment: It was the "name" attribute that was missing. I used the "id" attribute by mistake. Thanks